# dropdown menu with emmet

Tags: html, css, emmet

I have just started to learn emmet, and I am able to make simple menu structures with it, for example:

```
#navcontainer>ul>(li>a{Item$})*5
```

which generates this:

```
<div id="navcontainer">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But I would like to create something similar to this

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Item5</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

thanks :)

-Sohail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#navcontainer>ul>(li>a{Item$})*4+li.dropdown>a{item5}+.dropdown-content>a{Link $}*3
```

Edit:
Look also at this [cheat sheet](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/). There is everything you need to know about emmet